# How to disguise or encrypt hard-coded password for gmail sender in android studio

Tags: java, android, security, encryption

Looking for some security solutions for my "forgot password" activity. The current code that I am using requires me to hard-code my password into the source code so that anyone de-compiling would be able to access.

public class ForgotPassActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

```
private Button sendRequest;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_forgot_pass);

    sendRequest = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_send);

    sendRequest.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            new Thread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    try {
                        GMailSender sender = new GMailSender(
                                "sender@gmail.com",
                                "myPassword");
                        sender.sendMail("Test mail", "This mail has been sent from android app",
                                "sender@gmail.com",
                                "recipient@gmail.com");
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Error",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                }
            }).start();
        }
    });
}
```

}

public class GMailSender extends javax.mail.Authenticator {

```
private String mailhost = "smtp.gmail.com";
private String user;
private String password;
private Session session;

static {
    Security.addProvider(new com.provider.JSSEProvider());
}

public GMailSender(String user, String password) {
    this.user = user;
    this.password = password;

    Properties props = new Properties();
    props.setProperty("mail.transport.protocol", "smtp");
    props.setProperty("mail.host", mailhost);
    props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
    props.put("mail.smtp.port", "465");
    props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", "465");
    props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class",
            "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");
    props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.fallback", "false");
    props.setProperty("mail.smtp.quitwait", "false");

    session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props, this);
}

protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
    return new PasswordAuthentication(user, password);
}

public synchronized void sendMail(String subject, String body, String sender, String recipients) throws Exception {
    try{
        MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);
        DataHandler handler = new DataHandler(new ByteArrayDataSource(body.getBytes(), "text/plain"));
        message.setSender(new InternetAddress(sender));
        message.setSubject(subject);
        message.setDataHandler(handler);
        if (recipients.indexOf(',') > 0)
            message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, InternetAddress.parse(recipients));
        else
            message.setRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress(recipients));
        Transport.send(message);
    }catch(Exception e){
        Log.e("SendMail", e.getMessage(), e);
    }
}

public class ByteArrayDataSource implements DataSource {
    private byte[] data;
    private String type;

    public ByteArrayDataSource(byte[] data, String type) {
        super();
        this.data = data;
        this.type = type;
    }

    public ByteArrayDataSource(byte[] data) {
        super();
        this.data = data;
    }

    public void setType(String type) {
        this.type = type;
    }

    public String getContentType() {
        if (type == null)
            return "application/octet-stream";
        else
            return type;
    }

    public InputStream getInputStream() throws IOException {
        return new ByteArrayInputStream(data);
    }

    public String getName() {
        return "ByteArrayDataSource";
    }

    public OutputStream getOutputStream() throws IOException {
        throw new IOException("Not Supported");
    }
}
```

}

/*
 *  Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one or more
 *  contributor license agreements.  See the NOTICE file distributed with
 *  this work for additional information regarding copyright ownership.
 *  The ASF licenses this file to You under the Apache License, Version 2.0
 *  (the "License"); you may not use this file except in compliance with
 *  the License.  You may obtain a copy of the License at
 *
 *     http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
 *
 *  Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
 *  distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
 *  WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
 *  See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
 *  limitations under the License.
 */

import java.security.AccessController;
import java.security.Provider;

public final class JSSEProvider extends Provider {

```
public JSSEProvider() {
    super("HarmonyJSSE", 1.0, "Harmony JSSE Provider");
    AccessController.doPrivileged(new java.security.PrivilegedAction<Void>() {
        public Void run() {
            put("SSLContext.TLS",
                    "org.apache.harmony.xnet.provider.jsse.SSLContextImpl");
            put("Alg.Alias.SSLContext.TLSv1", "TLS");
            put("KeyManagerFactory.X509",
                    "org.apache.harmony.xnet.provider.jsse.KeyManagerFactoryImpl");
            put("TrustManagerFactory.X509",
                    "org.apache.harmony.xnet.provider.jsse.TrustManagerFactoryImpl");
            return null;
        }
    });
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot keep secret keys inside an android app.

You might want to implement the functionality in a back-end server. Just post the email to the server and the server will send the email in that address.

Comment: I like your solution! I was just thinking about doing that myself after I asked this question. Thank you for your answer.